# Can't get knn.py to work in Python installation (Anaconda)

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm currently using an Anaconda installation.
When I execute the code below, I get an error that states 'ImportError: No module named knn'
I've checked and I've got knn in the site-packages folder, which came with the Anaconda installation:
(....site-packages/PCV/classifiers/knn)
Any help on how to get this to work would be highly appreciated.

Part of my code:

```
import knn 
...
... 
model = knn.KnnClassifier( labels, vstack(( class_1, class_2)))
.....
.....
.....
```

Error message:

```
line 2, in <module>
    import knn

ImportError: No module named knn
```

Comment: full code:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67499044/classify.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the correct path within the PCV package. Try:

```
from PCV.classifiers import knn
```